# What is the collective term for a series of declarations?

Tags: single-word-requests

"The Cat sat on the mat" is a statement of fact consisting of a subject (The Cat), predicate (sat on), and an object (the mat).

If Susan declares/asserts that "The Cat sat on the mat", looking around, she might also assert that "The mat is green", that "The Cat is hungry" and "The Cat is brown". Additionally, she might refute the statements "Today is Tuesday" and "The Cat is a Persian Blue"

When collected together, these assertions/refutations form a picture of Susan's worldview, or at least help to illustrate this particular corner of the world from her perspective. What single word or phrase would you use to concisely describe such a package of information - expressed relatively formally in terms of precise, fact-based statements which are either asserted or refuted about the state of some part of the world at some point in time?

Allan might come along with a similar *packet* / *platform* / *set of factual statements* / *model* / *world-view* (though I don't particularly like any of these terms as written) which might agree or disagree with Susan's - I want a word to best describe such a collection, in the context of performing self-consistency tests (imagine Susan tries to assert "The Cat doesn't exist" amongst her other assertions) and cross-references to other *fact-collections*, in order to find areas of agreement/disagreement.

The process is kind of mathematical, so *sets* might apply, but I'm looking for something that carries a lot of these other connotations, should such a specific word exist.

Comment: I think linguists generally call *all* language-based actions ***conversations*** (not necessarily just *spoken, interactive* ones). So from [The Four Types of Conversations: Debate, Dialogue, Discourse, and Diatribe](https://medium.com/@DavidWAngel/the-four-types-of-conversations-debate-dialogue-discourse-and-diatribe-898d19eccc0a), your texts are probably all ***discourse(s)***. But they might be debate(s) or dialogue(s).

Comment: I'm liking *discourse*, and that lead me onto *treatise* which feels close.

Comment: It's what linguists mean by _context_.

Comment: Please note [the requirements for single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests).

Answer (score 1):

It seems a single word term will be hard to find, so I propose a two word expression (after comment by [user Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/599176/what-is-the-collective-term-for-a-series-of-declarations/599178?noredirect=1#comment1508426_599178)).

From the SOED, one gets  for the word "*utterance*" the definition below.

> **utterance** **3** That which is uttered or expressed in words; a spoken or occas. written statement or expression; an articulated sound.

Provided you see no inconvenient to the usage of "utterance" in this way being occasional, the following expression does describe this concept.

- *set of utterances*

Comment: So your answer is 'set'? (This is a SWR.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have no idea what an SWR might be (and there is  nothing evident in the way of explanations on the Web).

Comment: single word response ? probably…

Comment: @LPH "Single Word Request"

Comment: @user405662 Thanks for that precision!

Comment: Mathematicians and logicians discuss the [set of all propositions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199546/why-prop-set-of-all-propositions-is-a-set-by-zf-axioms), or a subset of this.

Comment: Yes, each Q is a subset taken from the *set of all propositions* that describes some (hopefully consistent) corner of the world. The entire world-view of an individual might be the collection (itself a Q) of all Q's where each Q defines what's known (or believed) to be true about a given domain. There is definitely a *set*-iness to this Q, but also something relating to perception, belief and perspective. So far, the best I've found is *treatise* because that's a formal and systematic setting out of a subject. I could adopt this (or similar) and make it a technical definition if I need to.

Comment: Reading more widely, [this post](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-coherence/) uses the phrase *set of propositions* which is exactly what the thing is, to which I was hoping to attach a word - from that article, something like a *coherence* might be a nice neologism since it references a known theory, and infers the presence that any such set have the property of coherence amongst its members.

Comment: @ThomasKimber  In such assertions as "The weather is nice there, although it is somewhat cold." it is not possible to speak of logical  formulas   (or propositions, as they are also called). Human language cannot be modeled entirely on the basis of the calculus of propositions, neither that of zero order logic (commonly referred to as *propositional calculus*) nor that of first order logic (when you introduce quantification (for all, there exists)). Each one of "The weather is nice there" and "it is somewhat cold" qualify as propositions (atomic), but the result of linking them in (1/2)

Comment: @ThomasKimber    "The weather is nice there, although it is somewhat cold." cannot be considered to be a formula in a calculus; however, we agree that it is a meaningful assertion in terms of human language. This means that if we want to introduce the terms of strict mathematical logic, we have to restrict the initial set of propositions to  atomic formulas, and the combinations are only those allowed by "and", "or" and "not". It's possibly not what you want. (2/2)